# contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Tags: swift, xcode

Learning a tutorial from Youtube, mine is xcode14, so the formulae UIview.animatewithDuration is not available, I am replacing it by the formula below but receiving error in the subjuct

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var HideTextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var hellolabel: UILabel!
    var textVisible: Bool=true
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func sayHello(_ sender: Any) {
        hellolabel.text="Hello Lisa"
    }
    
    @IBAction func hideText(_ sender: Any) {
        if textVisible{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {<#T##() -> Void#> in     self.hellolabel.alpha=0.0})
            self.hellolabel.isHidden=true
        } else {
            self.hellolabel.isHidden=false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {<#T##() -> Void#> in self.hellolabel.alpha=1.0})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode14, wow.  Just delete `<#T##() -> Void#> in`

Comment: Probably OP means iOS 14 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `<#T##() -> Void#> in` part of your code to compose the closure without any parameters:

```
@IBAction func hideText(_ sender: Any) {
    if textVisible{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.hellolabel.alpha=0.0
        })
        self.hellolabel.isHidden=true
    } else {
        self.hellolabel.isHidden=false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: { 
            self.hellolabel.alpha=1.0
        })
    }
}
```